# Retornar Enums (AJAX + JAVA + Spring Boot)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, json, spring-boot

```
# Enumerado
public enum EnumGenero {

    MAS("Masculino"),
    FEM("Feminino"),
    OUT("Outro"),
    NAE("Não especificado");

    private String desgen;

    EnumGenero(String desgen) {
        this.desgen = desgen;
    }

    public String getDesgen() {
        return desgen;
    }
}
```

```
# Função para consulta
    function carregarGeneros() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/genres',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            traditional: false,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#gencli").append(`<option value="${data[i]}">${data[i]}</option>`);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```
# Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerRest {

    @GetMapping("/genres")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object generos() {
        EnumGenero[] obj = null;
        try{
            obj = EnumGenero.values();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Estou precisando retornar os valores de um enumerado, name + desc utilizando ajax. No backend o objeto que recebe os valores e contém todos os valores (Segunda imagem). Porém, quando o ajax retorna os dados (data), contém somente um vetor com o name. Preciso retornar esse objeto conforme a segunda imagem, com todos os atribuitos. Alguém que talvez tenha passado ou possui experiência sobre, poderia ajudar?

Resultado Front
[image: Resultado Front]

Resultado Back
[image: Resultado Back]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Editado e especificado qual a necessidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isto

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerRest {

    @GetMapping("/genres")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> generos() {
        
        return Stream
                .of(EnumGenero.values())
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(EnumGenero::name, EnumGenero::getDesgen));
                    }
}
```

Será retornado um map do enum:

```js
{
   "NAE":"Não especificado",
   "MAS":"Masculino",
   "FEM":"Feminino",
   "OUT":"Outro"
}
```

Comment: Boa Dilermando, deu certo!
Fiz umas alterações no js para iterar sobre o resultado. 
Agradeço muito pela ajuda!

```
`function carregarGeneros() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/genres',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (const dataKey in data) {
                $("#gencli").append(`<option value="${dataKey}">${data[dataKey]}</option>`);
            }
        }
    });
}
```